# State of the art auto time sync?

Tags: debian, ntp, debian-squeeze, time-synchronization

Placing `ntpdate` into cron seems to be [no longer a good idea](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2002/12/msg04091.html).

What is an

- easy
- state-of-the-art
- automatic
- environmental friendly ;-)
- sleek

way of keeping a (debian) server's time clock up to date?

Comment: What version (of debian)?

Comment: The very article you linked to answers your question. What else do you need to know?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`apt-get install ntp`.  If you've never had it installed before, you should be good to go.  If you have, and therefore, might have stale config files, you could `apt-get remove --purge ntp` and `apt-get install ntp` again to get new config files.  Or if you want to keep your config files, I recommend checking that `/etc/default/ntp` has `NTPD_OPTS='-g'`.  This says to ntpd "try to correct the time, even if it is way off", and make sure at least one good server in `/etc/ntp.conf` has the `iburst` option, like:

```
server 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

This allows a burst of packets to be sent which will get your time synced quicker.

If you ever need to have something wait for time sync before proceeding, run `ntp-wait`.  If, for example, you have a service which shouldn't start until you are sure you have your time corrected.  (which you previously might have used ntpdate for)

Comment: Installing `ntp` is enough? No further configuration work required? That's it? No `ntpdate`?

Comment: that's it.  then you can run `ntpq -p` at any time to see how well it thinks it is doing.

Comment: What I did now: `apt-get remove --purge ntpdate` `apt-get remove --purge ntp` `apt-get install ntp`.

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just set ntpd to start at boot as suggested on the mailing list? That's what I've been doing for as long as I can remember.